# How to get Ingress portal ownership duration?

Tags: ingress

I wanted to know whether I can see a list of all my currently owned portals in Ingress, and I found [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146535/portal-list-available). So there's no way. But is there a way to know how long has a portal has been under ownership? For instance, I own a portal and I have its key too, then is there a way to know how long have I owned it?
P.S. This is for the Guardian badge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since June 2014 portal ownership date has been removed from Intel Map. You need to track manually the date you capture your portals.

Comment: why can't they just show the capture data for the owner only. I have no way to keep track of which dates i captured my portals. Now i have a 33 day streak going but i own like 160 portals i am not sure which one is the oldest.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good solution. Also, if you could view if you have ever owned or visited a portal it would be great to help you achieve _Visitor_ and _Pioneer_ badges.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible, or rather, you have to do it yourself.

<s>Yes, this is possible by using the [Ingress Intel Map](http://www.ingress.com/intel) - if you click on a portal there, you see the owner and the date since which they have held the portal:</s>

[image]

Comment: There's one thing thats still troubling me. Yesterday a very experienced player of the opposite faction pinged me saying that I will get a gold guardian badge soon. Thats why my this question, how did he get to know about my portal? (when even I dont know anything abt which portal he was talking about)

Comment: @Antrromet probably he was just checking that portal for his own reasons and noticed that. He probably pinged you to make you aware of that and eventually defend a portal in case of an attack.

Comment: @Kappei Ah...that makes sense! I just wish though, it would be awesome if we could somehow see all owned portals. Ingress tells me I am currently owning some 40-50 odd portals, but apart from some I've no clue which ones are those! :(

Comment: As of 06/17/14 the date has been removed from intel.  You'll need to keep up with these yourself for now.

Comment: This is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 2):

[image: iitc portal info screen cap]

If you use [IITC](http://iitc.jonatkins.com/) it is displayed on the portal info screen on the right in the form of owned since date/time. If you hover over it, then it gives an actual owned time.

Comment: "This site and the scripts are not officially affiliated with Ingress or Niantic Labs at Google. Using these scripts is likely to be considered against the Ingress Terms of Service. Any use is at your own risk."

Comment: I installed IITC today but it no longer displays the "since" time. I guess the source data was removed.

Comment: Yeah, it's long since been removed :(